# Section reminders at the top of each page?

Tags: sectioning

Is there a way to put a reminder of the current chapter/section/subsection at the top of each page under the header?  Something like the following:

[image: page 1][image: page 2]

but less awkward/ugly/distracting.  :)

### Ideas

Perhaps this can be done in a "start of new page" hook.  Does such a thing exist?

I tried using the [`afterpage`](http://ctan.org/pkg/afterpage) package as suggested in [a LaTeX Community forum thread](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=17155), but that didn't work (see [afterpage + list = missing \item](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51229/6185)).

### Motivation

I often find myself lost in long, complicated technical reference documents.  After a period of mind-numbing reading, I have no idea where in the forest I am because all I see are trees.  Printing the current chapter/section/subsection names at the top of each page would help me remember the context.

Comment: @N.N.:  I don't think putting this information in the header would work because headers have a fixed height (right?).  The top of a page might be in a subsubsection (depth 4 in the hierarchy, so maybe 4 lines of text) or just a chapter (only 1 line of text).

Comment: How are you reading these long technical documents?  I find reading them with the pdf table of contents visible helps me remember where I am.  (Of course, this will not work for printed documents.)

Comment: @mforbes:  I use Evince, but it doesn't do a good job of automatically highlighting the closest PDF bookmark as I scroll around.

Comment: also see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/122792/6185

Answer (score 3):

I almost have something figured out.  It involves patching the sectioning commands and using `\afterpage` to draw the reminders at the top of the next page.

Here is the code so far:

```
\makeatletter%
\newcounter{cont@level}%
\setcounter{cont@level}{-1}%
\newrobustcmd{\cont@err}[1]{\PackageError{cont}{can't patch \protect#1}{}}%
\apptocmd{\@part}{%
  \setcounter{cont@level}{0}\gdef\cont@part{#2}}{}{\cont@err{\@part}}%
\apptocmd{\@chapter}{%
  \setcounter{cont@level}{1}\gdef\cont@chapter{#2}}{}{\cont@err{\@chapter}}%
\apptocmd{\@sect}{%
  \global\defcounter{cont@level}{#2 + 1}%
  \csgdef{cont@#1}{#8}}{}{\cont@err{\@sect}}%
\newrobustcmd{\cont@showonnext}{%
  \afterpage{%
    \ifnumgreater{\value{cont@level}}{-1}{%
      \hbox{%
        \scriptsize%
        \itshape%
        \setlength{\fboxsep}{0.5pt}%
        \colorbox[gray]{0.9}{%
          \begin{minipage}[b]{\textwidth-2\fboxsep}%
            \noindent%
            \strut%
            Continued from:%
            \\\thepart{} \cont@part%
            \ifnumgreater{\value{cont@level}}{0}{%
              \\\thechapter{} \cont@chapter}{}%
            \ifnumgreater{\value{cont@level}}{1}{%
              \\\thesection{} \cont@section}{}%
            \ifnumgreater{\value{cont@level}}{2}{%
              \\\thesubsection{} \cont@subsection}{}%
            \ifnumgreater{\value{cont@level}}{3}{%
              \\\thesubsubsection{} \cont@subsubsection}{}%
            \strut%
          \end{minipage}%
        }%
        \strut%
        \vspace{\baselineskip}%
      }%
    }{}%
    \cont@showonnext%
  }%
}%
\cont@showonnext%
\makeatother%
```

The code is quite rough (I'm no TeXnician), but it mostly does what I want.  It puts a gray box at the top of each page like the example in the question.  Here are some of its problems:

- It creates an extra page at the end of the document with a continued block.  This should be easy to fix.
- There are problems if a part starts at the top of a new page:

  - It doesn't know that the previous part ended.  I'm not sure how to detect the end of a part.  See my other question [Macro that knows it is at the end of a section?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51433/6185)
  - The text is wrong.  I'm guessing this is because the command for the new part (e.g., `\section`) is executed before the page break decision is made.  I think I'll have to use marks to fix this.
  - Sometimes it draws the reminder text under the section title (it's as if the original page break was changed in the output routine)
- It doesn't work with the starred versions of `\section`, etc.
- It was written with `report` in mind; it might not work right for other classes
- The output is ugly.  The code itself is probably ugly too.  :)

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to redefine `\sectionmark` and `\subsectionmark`. This can be done as follows:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
```

This will produce the same look as in the pictures, but now without the section/subsection numbers and in ordinary letters instead of capital letters. If you still would want the section/subsection numbers, then a posibbility is:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesubsection \quad #1}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{\thesection \quad #1}{}}
```

There is one important thing to note. The two `\renewcommand` MUST appear AFTER the command `\pagestyle{fancy}`. Besides this there is infinitely many possibilities for choosing a formating of these 'reminders' should look.

What the commands `\markright` and `\markboth` do is that, `\markright` sets the value of `\rightmark` and `\markboth` sets the value of both `\leftmark` and `\rightmark`. These commands `\leftmark` and `\rightmark` can thus be used to customize the headder and footer, e.g. as follows:

```
\lfoot{}
\rfoot{}
\cfoot{ \thepage }
\rhead{ {\scshape \leftmark} }
\lhead{ {\scshape \rightmark} }
\chead{}
```

The reason why you would want to set the `\rightmark` to be blank when setting the `\leftmark` as done in the solutions with `\renewcommand` above, is that you would not want, e.g., to list the name of the last subsection of the previous section untill you create a subsection in the new section.

If you have choosen a documentclass that supports chapters then you should do the above construction with `\chaptermark` replacing `\sectionmark` and `\sectionmark` replacing `\subsectionmark`.

Comment: I think my example images may have been misleading; I revised them to get rid of the header.  I don't think modifying the headers will work---if the top of the page is in a subsubsection, I might want 4 lines of text:  one for the chapter name, one for the section name, one for the subsection name, and one for the subsubsection name.