# afterpage + list = missing \item

Tags: errors, lists, page-breaking, environments, boxes

I'm trying to use the [`afterpage`](http://ctan.org/pkg/afterpage) package to automatically insert text at the top of each page (please see my other question [Section reminders at the top of each page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51129/6185)) but I'm having trouble.

Sometimes I get unlucky and a list environment starts just before a page break.  The first `\item` doesn't appear until just after the page break.  When this happens, LaTeX gives me a "missing `\item`" error message because `\afterpage` is inserting text right after the start of a list environment.

Here is a minimal example that emulates the problem I'm seeing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\begin{document}
\afterpage{afterpage-stuff}
before list
\begin{itemize}
\clearpage
\item an item
\end{itemize}
after list
\end{document}
```

If I remove that `\clearpage`, then everything works as expected.

Is there something I can pass to `\afterpage` that would temporarily reset TeX's state so that I can safely insert some vertical mode material (e.g., a `minipage`) at the top of the next page without interfering with environments that span pages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\afterpage{\hbox{afterpage-stuff}}
```

gets rid of the error but it depends what you want the spacing to be....

This does allow vertical material for example

```
\afterpage{\hbox{%
\parbox{\textwidth}{afterpage-stuff

some more}}}
```