# Macro that knows it is at the end of a section?

Tags: macros, sectioning

In [Is it a bad idea to use \begin{section} ... \end{section} in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12001/6185), Jan Hlavacek says:

> Of course it is typically possible to recognize an end of a section, but there is actually a number of ways how a section can end: start of another section, start of the next chapter or part, start of `\endmatter`, bibliograpy, index, etc, or the end of document.

How would I go about writing a macro that recognizes when it is at the end of a section?

I'd like it to work properly in [`\afterpage`](http://ctan.org/pkg/afterpage) so that I can fix some of the issues in [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51245/6185) to [Section reminders at the top of each page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51129/6185)  I believe this means that it'll have to use marks to detect where it is in relation to a sectioning command, but I don't know enough about LaTeX to be certain.

For example, I'd like to be able to do something like the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\newcommand{\printendedsections}{%
    \ifatendofsubsubsection{(end of subsubsection \thesubsubsection)}{}%
    \ifatendofsubsection{(end of subsection \thesubsection)}{}%
    \ifatendofsection{(end of section \thesection)}{}%
    \ifatendofchapter{(end of chapter \thechapter)}{}%
    \ifatendofpart{(end of part \thepart)}{}%
}
\begin{document}

% will expand to '(end of subsection 2.1)' at the top of page 2 because
% subsection 2.2 starts right at the top of page 2
\afterpage{\hbox{\printendedsections}}

\section{sec1}

asdf
\printendedsections% expands to nothing because section 1 hasn't ended yet

\subsection{sub1.1}

\printendedsections% expands to nothing because subsection 1.1 hasn't ended yet
asdf
\printendedsections% expands to '(end of subsection 1.1)(end of section 1)'

\section{sec2}

asdf
\printendedsections% expands to nothing because section 2 hasn't ended yet

\subsection{sub2.1}

pretend there is enough content here
to push the start of subsection 2.2
to the top of the next page
\printendedsections% expands to '(end of subsection 2.1)'

\subsection{sub2.2}

asdf
\printendedsections% expands to '(end of subsection 2.2)(end of section 2)'

\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50783/5763

Comment: Most of the negative comments in the referred question are related to the grouping introduced by the environment. It would be easy to define macros for "sectioning environments" which don't introduce groups but are still able to check for proper nesting, for example. And you'd have an explicit place to bind the section ending stuff to. Any other solution to your request would be really awkward.

Comment: @StephanLehmke:  Requiring users to declare the end of a section would make this much easier, but it would mean that I couldn't write a package that others could just drop into their documents and use.

Comment: @RichardHansen wouldn't this hold for `\printendedsections` as well? Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you really wish to achieve.

Comment: @StephanLehmke: `\printendedsections` is a contrived example to illustrate the general idea.  I'm interested in a general solution mostly because I'm curious and I think it will come in handy in the future, but also because I have a [specific problem](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51245/6185) I'd like to solve.

Comment: I'd try doing this with a different API.  I.e. have a macro to register AtEndOfSection code, and modify the sectioning commands appropriately.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As requested the problem can't be resolved (with input similar to the example). TeX is sequentially working and when it executes `\printendedsections` in running text there is no way for TeX to know if the next thing that comes up is more text, some heading or ...

Even with a multi-pass solution it is next to impossible to determine, at least not if you do not additionally modify the heading commands as well, as one would need to determine what (if anything) is between `\printendedsections` and the next heading command.

Ignoring, for the moment, the additional request to determine if a section starts on the top of the page, the problem of automatically outputting text when a section level ends can be accomplished in a number of ways. Here is one that does everything automagically:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@startsection%
    { \par}{\par \outputsectionends{#2}}%
    {\typeout{*** SUCCESS ***}}{\typeout{*** FAIL ***}}

\def\perhapssomethingended #1{%
        \ifnum \arabic{#1}>\z@
           (end of #1 \csname the#1\endcsname)%
       \fi
}
\makeatother

\def\outputsectionends #1{%
   \ifcase #1\relax
% extend here (+ \chapter command) for report/book class
   \or
      \perhapssomethingended{subsubsection}
      \perhapssomethingended{subsection}
      \perhapssomethingended{section}
      \setcounter{subsubsection}{0}         % need to reset high-level headings as LaTeX is lazy and only resets the next level
  \or
      \perhapssomethingended{subsubsection}
      \perhapssomethingended{subsection}
  \or
      \perhapssomethingended{subsubsection}
 \fi
\par
}

\AtEndDocument{\outputsectionends1}

\begin{document}
\section{sec1} asdf
\subsection{sub1.1}    asdf
\subsection{sub1.2}    asdf
\subsubsection{sub1.2.1}    asdf
\paragraph{sub1.2.1.1}    this level is not taken into account  (but could of course)
\paragraph{sub1.2.1.2}    this level is not taken into account 
\section{sec2} asdf
\subsection{sub2.1}
\subsection{sub2.2} asdf

\end{document}
```

### Explanation:

We hook into `\@startsection` which is the standard LaTeX interface for producing headings (other than chapter). We know that if this command is called a heading with "level number" `#2` is being generated (a section is 1, a subsection 2 ...).

So we do different things depending on the number: if we start a section (1) then we may have ended a "subsubsection" and perhaps a "subsection" and perhaps a previous "section". So we run `\perhapssomethingended` for each. This command looks at the value of the current counter (given as its argument), say for "subsection" and if this value is greater then zero, then there has been a previous heading. Thus we output some text.

There is only one catch: LaTeX is lazy and when it starts a new heading it only resets the next heading level to zero but not all higher heading levels (as this will later on recursively happen anyway). However, for us this is a problem because it means that after "subsubsection 1.2.1" its value will stay at 1, thus messing up the output when "subsection 2.1" is processed. Therefore we explicitly have to ensure that the subsubsection counter is reset when we process a section (you can try it out by commenting the `\setcounter` line out).

Finally we also need to end everything at the end of the document. This is done by pretending that this place acts like another section, i.e., we run `\outputsectionends{1}` there.

If you run this you will get:

[image]

Of course there are several improvements possible including, e.g., how the resulting text is formatted (which for now is simply as a paragraph with indentation by itself).

### Detecting sections on the top of the page

Obviously this doesn't work with `\afterpage` as it all happens behind the scene. However afterpage isn't the right tool anyway here, as it drops in something in an asyncronous way after the main galley has already been processed and this isn't going to help.

The approach that I would use instead is adding labels before and after the breakpoint that is added by the heading. Thus if both end up on the same page, then no break was taken at this point and if they end up on different pages, then the break happened directly in front of the heading. In that case `\outputsectionends` could change its behavior as necessary (obviously that would result in multiple runs before the document stabilizes, especially if the amount of text generated changes a lot depending on the situation). I'm not too sure though what is wanted by the OP so I'm not going to flesh this out.

### Providing this solution for parts or chapter

In a comment it was asked if this solution would work also `\part` or `\chapter`. The answer is yes and no. Not out of the box with the code above. It needs extending the code in two ways

1. `\chapter`and `\part` are normally not defined using `\@startsection`. Thus their code would need to be patch in a similar way, so that before they generate the heading (and possibly a page break etc) the `\outputsectionends` is run.
2. In addition `\outputsectionends` would need to be changed: the hierarchy level of `\chapter` is 0 and that of `\part` is -1. So the `\ifcase` could be extended to accomodate chapter (there is already a comment in the code where to place the actions), but for `\part` one needs to additionally test for `#1` being -1 if `\ifcase` only runs through 0, 1, 2, ...

### Update

In a comment it was asked what I mean by adding labels before and after the break. What `\@startsection` uses to generate the possible breakpoint is:

```
 \addpenalty\@secpenalty\addvspace\@tempskipa
```

and the commands `\addpenalty` and `\addvspace` are a little tricky so that we can't simply add labels before and after. Why? Because they look backwards to detect if there is a vertical space in front and if so move the space after the penalty or combine it with the additionally requested space (in case of `\addvspace`).  So if we put a label in front of `\addpenalty` it means that any previous space is hidden by it. Therefore we need to provide our own version that mimics `\addpenalty` and also adds a label:

```
\def\addpenaltywithlabel#1#2{%
  \ifvmode
    \if@minipage
    \else
      \if@nobreak
      \else
        \ifdim\lastskip=\z@
          \label{#2}%          <- one place for the label
          \penalty#1\relax
        \else
          \@tempskipb\lastskip
          \vskip -\lastskip
          \label{#2}%          <- and here if the previous skip is "moved"
          \penalty#1%
          \vskip\@tempskipb
        \fi
      \fi
    \fi
  \else
    \@noitemerr
  \fi}
```

Adding the second label after the `\addvspace` is fine as that will be followed by the heading title. There is of course a lot more to do, the labels need to be different for each instance (for example by using a counter that is incremented) and one has to write a comparison for the page values they generate. And then one has to write some code that actually makes use of this information that the heading appears right at the top (hand waving :-)

Comment: Mittelback Did not try it out, but off the top of my head will fail for starred versions. Better to add a flag or boolean to keep track of sections. Set it at one after the command. Test before it, if one end of section etc.. Pretty much like one would keep track of brackets in a compiler.

Comment: @Yiannis the name is Middle spring or creek if you and to anglizise me ;-) but back to the question: it can't fail on star commands as there is no spec on what they should produce when ending ... their title? This would bring us to quite another ball game

Comment: Oops! Sorry about the name my bad. The reason I brought the starred version of the command, is that a lot of books end sections with ornaments. This sort of books very rarely have sections numbered.

Comment: @Yiannis no problem (about the name - you aren't the first one ... most often it is Mittleback or a slight variation). Anyway, yes I understand that. My solution is not adequate to *monitor*  or trap the heading structure including starred ones, but that wasn't asked for, was it?

Comment: @FrankMittelbach  I was wondering if it would work if I would replace section with part?  I would like to have this effect at the end of each part in a beamer presentation -- its where I also finaly ask if there is questions about the part that was covered.

Comment: @Louis I added some explanation to to extend this code for \part and \chapter. But I assume that what are looking for is simpler: doubt that you are interested in which sections and subsections have ended, but just in the fact that a part has ended. In that case I would be lazy and just put such a slide in before each part, or define a macro that does it for me.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach Well I would to be more lazy and also to add something in a "preamble" to remember it on my behalf.  On the other hand I rarely have more than 4 part, which I learnt is better to split into separate presentations.

Comment: By "adding labels before and after the breakpoint added by the heading", do you mean add `\label` before and after `\addpenalty\@secpenalty\addvspace\@tempskipa` in the definition of `\@startsection` (e.g., by using `\pretocmd` on both `\@startsection` and `\@xsect`)?

Comment: @RichardHansen that a bit more complicated, so can't answer that in a comment. Have instead updated the full answer above.

Comment: Thanks for the update!  It seems to me that eTeX marks would be easier than labels for detecting when a section starts at the top of a new page.  For example, put `\marks1{starts at top of page}` before the break, `\marks1{starts in middle of page}` after the break, and look at `\botmarks1` in `\afterpage`.  Do I misunderstand how marks and labels work?  (Sorry for all of these questions, I'm still very new to all of this.)

Comment: @RichardHansen different not simpler really. marks like labels will prevent \addpenalty from looking backwards so you need the same trick to keep this working. The difference is then that you can evauate marks in the output routine while you can evaluate the label status in the galley, ie when processing the heading. So it depends on what you want to achieve: if the heading should change look and feel if it is on top of a page -> labels. If the page layout should change if a heading is on top of the page, then marks would be better.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand.  Thank you very much!