# Is there an end equivalent to AtBeginPart in beamer?

Tags: beamer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Macro that knows it is at the end of a section?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51433/macro-that-knows-it-is-at-the-end-of-a-section)

I am looking for an equivalent to `\AtBeginPart` that would operate at the end of a `\part`.  It would save me time.

If it does not exist, how would one go about to construct something like that?

Comment: Slightly related question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51433/86

Comment: @AndrewStacey I looked at the reference and will try to hack it to work for \part, I am just not sure if I can for instance in that code replace section with part.  I will post a comment there and hope to get a response.

Comment: @AndrewStacey Frank Mittelbach edited his answer and it seems that it could or could not be done, as it could not always work -- a YES/NO extension to his original answer. I am just to busy now to try it, but I will definitely try it soon.

Comment: So can this question then not have an answer?