# HTML Navigation

Tags: hyperref, memoir, html, navigation, htlatex

I have a large document written in LaTeX (memoir class) that I also use to produce HTML, using:

```
htlatex.exe "Test.tex" "html,3" "" "Test" "--interaction=nonstopmode"
```

I've been attempting to find a more efficient navigation method than the "prev,next,front,up" that is produced by default. A blog located [here](http://www.cvr.cc/?p=504) indicates that there are options built in that should give me a sidebar, however, the `frames` option just produces a blank title page and `obj-toc` doesn't produce anything different from the default settings.

One of the other ideas I thought of was a "breadcrumb" navigation using the hyperref package. I've tried the breadcrumb package (post by Sean Allred) at [this stack exchange post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122792/breadcrumb-hyperlink-header) , however, these breadcrumbs (which look great in the PDF) do not appear at all in the HTML version.

Any help in this would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: P.S. I am using FireFox as my browser.

Comment: does your document compile without errors? if there are errors, `frames` option may work incorrectly. Maybe you should try to produce the mwe

Comment: @michal.h21 While attempting to produce a MWE I was able to get the `frames` option to work, it seems the fact that I had chapter* and section* caused a problem. I also see,however, that this is not really what I wanted since it removes the TOC from the main page and places it in a sidebar. The main criteria is that this navigation should be visible on all (web)pages in the document and have some kind of hierarchical display that shows `(Part->Chapter->Section)` or `(Chapter->Section)` for the current `Section` that I am viewing. I'm not really sure what kind of MWE I could produce.

Comment: @michal.h21 I've created a header using HTML/CSS that behaves as desired (so far), with a minimal example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wy2Uf/). So now my question becomes, is there a way that I can, while viewing a specific section, reference the part and chapter that it belongs to? It seems like this should be possible using the hyperref package but I'm not sure how I would need to configure the hook/anchor. Also, once those references are established, I'm not completely sure how to insert the code to create the header on the section pages (custom config for htlatex, scripting?).